# How to use recursion in quicksort algorithm in c?

Tags: c, quicksort

This is my first time posting so bear with me! I have to make a quicksort algorithm as an assignment for university, using c. However, when I try running the program a pop-up window opens up and informs me that the exe has stopped working. So then I started debugging and I found that the problem appears when the program enters the recursion process, as I receive around those lines a SIGSEGV type error. Unfortunately I cant find the problem so that's why I'm posting here my code, hoping that you can help me. Any further advice about my code in general will be appreciated. Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 20
void quicksort(int *first, int *last);
main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    int *ptr, arr[SIZE], k;
    ptr=arr;
    fp=fopen("numbers.txt", "r");
    printf("Initial array before sorting:\n");
    for (k=0; k<SIZE; k++)
    {
        fscanf(fp, "%d", ptr);
        printf("Element[%d]:\t%d\n", k+1, *ptr);
        ptr++;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    printf("Final array after sorting:\n");
    quicksort(arr, arr+SIZE-1);
    for (k=0; k<SIZE; k++)
    {
        printf("Element[%d]:\t%d\n", k+1, *(arr+k));
    }   
}
void quicksort(int *first, int *last)
{
    int *item_left, *item_right, *i, *j, *pivot, temp, check_left=0, check_right=0, limiter=0;
    pivot=last;
    while (!check_left && !check_right && limiter<10)
    {
        for (i=first; i<last; i++)
        {
            if (*i>*pivot)
            {
                item_left=i;
                check_left=1;
                break;
            }
        }
        for (j=last; j>first; j--)
        {
            if (*j<*pivot)
            {
                item_right=j;
                check_right=1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (check_left==1 && check_right==1)
        {
            temp=*item_left;
            *item_left=*item_right;
            *item_right=temp;
            check_left=0;
            check_right=0;
        }
        limiter++;
    }
    temp=*item_right;
    *item_right=*pivot;
    *pivot=temp;
    if (last-first>1)//-------problem
    {
        quicksort(first, item_left-1);
        quicksort(item_left, last);
    }//----------problem
}
```

Comment: I haven't examined the code carefully, but you're probably not detecting the base case correctly, so recursing infinitely.

Comment: Run it in the debugger with a small array, so you can see why the recursion isn't stopping.

Comment: Unrelated: Your `main` function is invalid. It should return `int`.

Comment: The first problem I noticed is that `item_right` may be uninitialized at `*item_right = *pivot;`

Comment: Shouldn't the quicksort part be something like quicksort(first, item_left-1); quicksort(item_left+1, last);

Comment: What's the rationale behind `limiter` - is that just a debugging attempt?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I used limiter so that the while statement stops looping indefinitely. I know it isn't the best way to do it, but it is simple and gets the work done.

Comment: @bot-coder101 Yes you're right. I've changed it, although the code still doesn't work.

Comment: @HLIAS095 Did you fix the problem with `item_right`being uninitialized when you do `*item_right = *pivot`? That makes your program have _undefined behavior_ and just about _anything_ could happen.

Comment: @TedLyngmo yeah it seems that was a problem too! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So I checked the code again and I found the problem. You see, I declared some local variables in the function I was calling. This was causing trouble in the computer's memory, as every time the function was called again, it was told to create the same variables which were already created and stored in the memory. So what I did is to make all those variables needed global. This way they are created only one time.

Comment: Using global variables for this is following an anti-pattern that makes it impossible to call the function from different threads at the same time (and get the expected result) etc. Pass the variables as arguments to the function instead.